# How to fix Raspberry pi python microphone

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm using WebCamera microphone

I'm trying to get microphone speech and convert to text

I'm using Raspberry Pi 3 and python3

I have changed alsa.conf

sudo nano /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf

defaults.ctl.card 1

defaults.pcm.card 1

defaults.pcm.device 0

defaults.pcm.subdevice 0

My Code

```
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
mic = sr.Microphone()
mic = sr.Microphone(device_index=0)
with mic as source:
    audio = r.listen(source)
print(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

My Error

```
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM 
cards.pcm.center_lfe

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM 
cards.pcm.phoneline

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM 
cards.pcm.phoneline

ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'defaults.bluealsa.device'

ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib conf.c:4996:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file 
or directory

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa

ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 
'defaults.bluealsa.device'

ALSA lib conf.c:4528:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer 
returned error: No such file or directory

ALSA lib conf.c:4996:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file 
or directory

ALSA lib pcm.c:2495:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa

ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1052:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave

Cannot connect to server socket err = No such file or directory

Cannot connect to server request channel

jack server is not running or cannot be started

JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping 
unlock

JackShmReadWritePtr::~JackShmReadWritePtr - Init not done for -1, skipping 
unlock
```